# Android: Issues while displaying image with url in webview

Tags: android, webview, imageview

I am displaying some images in my webview with the help of their urls and i want them to be in center of the available space but images are being aligned at top and one more thing i am creating the webview dynamically to display in viewpager.Actually i am trying to implement functionality which should be like currently available in facebook application for android devices.

thanks.

Comment: Use javascript to align it to the center

Comment: @Zacharias : its not about just one image here i need to display about 100 images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ought to be able to wrap the images in html and center them via css. Done it in one of my apps.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

private static final String HTML_FORMAT = "<html><body style=\"text-align: center; background-color: black; vertical-align: center;\"><img src = \"%s\" /></body></html>";
private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.yourWebView);

    final String imgUrl = "http://db.tt/2283dXLT";
    final String html = String.format(HTML_FORMAT, imgUrl);

    mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

You should be able to display any number of images just by changing the imgUrl.

Comment: i tried your code but  unfortunate for me its not working .+1 for yor help

Comment: What is happening? Are you getting an exception or is the image not displaying or...?

Comment: no i am not getting any error but image is not coming in center.

Comment: Can you post the xml code for your WebView? What are the height and width set to?

Comment: actually i am not using xml here i am creating these webviews dynamically.

Comment: What are you setting the height and width to then?

Comment: i am giving both fill_parent and image is aligning top of my view

Comment: please have a look:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582132/cannot-align-webview-image-in-centre-of-a-dialog ...I tried your answer,but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your code and find solution.
In additon to above code you need to put the below code in  onCreate().

```
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
```