# Cannot align webview image in centre of a dialog

Tags: android, html, webview

I want to align image in a **webview** to the centre of a dialog.

**Relevant code:**

```
void showImageInLargeMode(String link)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater=ThirtyArticleDetail.this.getLayoutInflater();
        View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.showenlargeimagedialog,null);
        final Dialog d1 = new Dialog(ThirtyArticleDetail.this);
        d1.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        d1.setContentView(layout);
        d1.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
        wvdisplayimage=(WebView)layout.findViewById(R.id.wvdisplayimage);
        wvdisplayimage.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wvdisplayimage.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f0ece9"));
        wvdisplayimage.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wvdisplayimage.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<style>img{display: inline;height: auto;max-width: 100%;}</style><img src='" + link + "'/>", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
        //wvdisplayimage.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<img src='" + link + "'/>", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

        //wvdisplayimage.loadData("<html><head><style type='text/css'>body{margin:auto auto;text-align:center;} img{width:100%25;} </style></head><body><img src=''" + link + "'/></body></html>" ,"text/html",  "UTF-8");


        /*String html = "<html><body><img src=\"" + link + "\" width=\"100%\" \"/></body></html>";
        wvdisplayimage.loadData(html, "text/html", null);*/



        d1.show();


        btncanceldialog=(Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.btncancelredicon);
        btncanceldialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                d1.dismiss();

            }
        });

    }
```

**showenlargeimagedialog.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llshowmoredialog"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="2dp" >

    <!-- Contents will go here.. -->

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wvdisplayimage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >
    </WebView>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btncancelredicon"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button_background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="X"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see the image in webview is diaplaying **at the top of the dialog**.**How to move the image in centre??**

I have tried many other solutions in SO,but none of them seems working.
Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `wrap_content` instead `match_parent` in your `WebView` layout

Comment: Thank you,it worked,but when i zoom the image,it is not expanding,any idea?

Comment: @kgandroid ok try another way, you can keep using `match_parent` in your `WebView` layout, but using `gravity="center"` instead `layout_gravity="center"`

Comment: sorry for late reply.Tried it,but not working :(  Image is aligned at the top

Comment: @kgandroid you can try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783146/android-center-and-adjust-image-in-webview.

Comment: @kgandroid i think you can simple align your image by using html attribute. So the image will stand at center of your page.

Comment: yes i Have tried that way also...but unfortunately the I didnt get the result :(

Answer (score 0):

Pass this style `android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen` Dialog constructor :

```
 final Dialog d1 = new Dialog(ThirtyArticleDetail.this,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

Comment: Not working,the dialog is coming fullscreen,but the image is still aligned to top